# Letting git know that a file was renamed - OS X file renamed from lowercase to uppercase shows as untracked

Tags: file, git-status

I renamed a folder without using **git mv** or any other git command, from lowercase to uppercase, now git shows the new folder as not tracked and at the same time is tracking files inside the folder.

I renamed "Jogo do rato" to "Jogo do Rato" and than made a **git add --all**. Git found new files and changes as it should but it now shows every folder inside "Jogo do Rato" as untracked. I would like to get rid of this "untracked" files, but am at loss as what way to go.

I'm using OS X Snow Leopard, my drive is in Mac OS Extended (Journaled), case insensitive and git version 1.6.6.

Regards,

Sérgio

Answer (score 6):

I manage to find a way to solve the problem. I changed the config option `core.ignorecase` from `true` to `false`, re-added the files that git was always seeing as new files, and commited my changes.

I'm still looking to see if I lost something or if anything is in a state that shouldn't be but I think I was able to solve this problem.